# No syntax error but code fails

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code

```
var per_page = 5;

// Page will start from 0 and Multiple by Per Page
var start_from = 0;

Noder.query('SELECT * FROM crud LIMIT "'+start_from+'", "'+per_page+'"', function(err, results) {
});
```

which is syntactically valid but produces undefined when i

`console.log(results)`

I used this validator to check for errors http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

The problem is not my variables since i have confirmed they hold the desired data.Is there an error that is keeping my snippet from working?.

Comment: Have you checked what `err` contains?

Comment: @Juhana  Yes and  Its null

Comment: Have you tried it without `"`? `('SELECT * FROM crud LIMIT ' + start_from + ', ' + per_page + ', function(...`

Comment: print the whole query and test it against a db to see if it contains errors

Comment: @AlexSzabó without " its an error.

Comment: @LeQs what's the error? Syntax? Are you using MySQL?

Comment: @AlexSzabó Yes,i am using mysql.

Comment: @BeNdErR cool concept.I have been thinking of doing that,but i dont know how.But i have an idea.

Comment: @BeNdErR That reall helped. I printed the query and look what i found `SELECT * FROM crud LIMIT "'+start_from+'", "'+per_page+'"` I have been sending the a query with `"` After printing `SELECT * FROM crud LIMIT "0", "5"`

Comment: Why are you quoting the numerical limit?

Comment: @DaveNewton That was the error all along. I split the code and i got rid of the quotes as and te query works as expected. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete the `"`, because `limit` needs numbers.

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants ... [[Source]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

```js
var per_page = 5; 
var start_from = 0;

document.write('SELECT * FROM crud LIMIT "' + start_from + '", "' + per_page + '"');
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM crud LIMIT "0", "5" ` is a mysql syntax error

Comment: @LeQs, yes therfore delete the `"`.